# How to print all pending signals using a SYSCALL in UNIX?

Tags: c, unix, kernel

I've been attempting to create a custom syscall that prints various information about a process. Of that information is the pending signals. I understand that under task_struct is another struct called sigpending, which is defined as follows:

```
struct sigpending {
                 struct list_head list;
                 sigset_t signal;   };
```

So I originally attempted using list_for_each_entry but that requires knowing the name of the member in the struct that stores the pending signals which I can't seem to find.

So how would I go about printing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is checking [pending] sigset_t bits and print signals as numbers, or strings, or a mix.
Easily adapted to a kernel version, this example is shown as working user code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

// partial list for printing as strings:
static char *sigstrs[_NSIG] = {
    [SIGHUP] = "HUP",
    [SIGSEGV] = "SEGV",
};

static void show_pending(char *str, sigset_t *ssetp)
{
    int signo;

    printf(str);
    for (signo = 1; signo < _NSIG; signo++) {
        if (sigismember(ssetp, signo) == 0)
            continue;
        else if (sigstrs[signo])
            printf(" SIG%s", sigstrs[signo]);
        else
            printf(" %d", signo);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    // user simulation, &taskp->pending.signal;
    sigset_t pending;
    memset(&pending, 0, sizeof (pending));
    sigaddset(&pending, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&pending, SIGSEGV);

    show_pending("pending:", &pending);
    return (0);
}
```

---

Output:
`pending: SIGHUP SIGSEGV`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm having issues implementing the solution though. I'm using the same show_pending definition, only swapping `printf` with  `printk`. I've defined the sigset_t as `sigset_t pending = proces->pending.signal` where proces is the current task_struct process. I have a test script that blocks a signal and then calls it to itself twice, but it doesn't seem to be stored in pending.

Comment: Suggest confirming that `current` really is the task of interest instead; for related signal info, check out the several calls to `render_sigset_t()` at the end of [task_sig()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/array.c#L265)

Comment: Alright, so it seems that for whatever reason, the current process's pending.signal set is empty. Any idea on what else I could access? I'm sure that I'm accessing the correct process as the rest of the information printed is correct. This is the code I'm used to check as well:
`mask = sigblock(sigmask(SIGUSR2));
 kill(pid, SIGUSR2); `

Comment: Maybe some reading starting at [do_sigpending()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/signal.c#L3089)